# Python: I need to create a random NxN Matrix with certain specifications

Tags: python, function, matrix

I'm doing a math homework problem that's giving me a bit of trouble. I need to write a python function that creates a random matrix such that:

- the matrix is NxN
- Each off-diagonal entry ( where ≠) is a random number in [0,1)
- A diagonal entry   is a random number in  [,+1)

Here's what I have so far, but I don't think I understand indexing for an array, so I'm coming up with problems

```
def randmat(n):
    matrix = np.ndarray((n,n), dtype=float)
    for i,j in range(0,n):
        if i != j:
            matrix[ij] = np.random.rand(1)
        else:
            matrix[ij] = n + np.random.rand(1)
    return matrix
```

If you know what I'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For a multidimensional numpy array you can access the elements with `matrix[i][j]` instead of `matrix[ij]`

Comment: _so I'm coming up with problems_ What problems? Please see [ask], [mcve], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below:

```
def randmat(n):
    matrix = np.ndarray((n,n), dtype=float)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if i != j:
                matrix[i,j] = np.random.rand(1)
            else:
                matrix[i,j] = n + np.random.rand(1)
    return matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `numpy`, accessing elements of the matrix can be done in two ways: `matrix[i][j]` or `matrix[i, j]`

Also, in `for` loop, you are trying to get two values from `range`, which actually yields only one. So you can't loop like this with `i` and `j`.

I would propose the following solution for your problem

```
def randmat(n):
    matrix = np.random.rand(n, n)
    for i in range(n):
        matrix[i, i] = n + np.random.rand(1)
    return matrix
```

`numpy.random.rand` is a nice function, which gives you the matrix of desired shape with elements, randomly distributed between 0 and 1. Here is the documentaion: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html#numpy.random.rand

Then, you only have to iterate once and change elements on main diagonal.

Hope this will help